# SUMPRODUCT over muliple ranges issue

Tags: excel, formulas

This maybe a question already asked but I have not been able to word it properly to do a search.

I am fully aware that `SUMPRODUCT` can be refered to as a select statement and have been using this for some time as such.

However, I have hit an instance where I only need to trigger the sum under mutlple conditions.

The base statement is:-

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM Orders WHERE Gencode="GEN0368"
```

and the resulting sumproduct is:-

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C32) * (B2:B32="GEN0368"))
```

The hard bit is to make the sum product appear only when another condition is triggered.

Doing so via a single criteria was easy enough with:-

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C32) * (B2:B32="GEN0368") * (J2:J32="W3019100582"))
```

But I need that second criteria to be a range, this is where I am coming up stuck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

`=SUMPRODUCT(C2:C32,(B2:B32="GEN0368")*ISNUMBER(MATCH(J2:J32,Your_range,0)))`

where Your_range can be an actual range (single column or row), or an array entered like this {"abc","xyz","stu"}

Comment: You my friend are a legend...I knew the internet would win!!